# Reasoning for redundant "natural" (but not courtesy accidental)

Tags: notation, key-signatures, accidentals

I understand why you'd add courtesy accidentals, but I was browsing through some old sheet music lying around here and came across this, and can't seem to come up with a reason for this natural in bar 2:

[image]

What am i missing here? The signature's G and only the F's should be raised, so why naturalise the G's? I don't have any training, so maybe this is simply something I've missed in my self-study.

(It's from "Alec Eiffel" by Pixies BTW)

==edit==

[image]

Comment: could you please poste a few more bars and the staff of F clef too?
I assume there could be a G# in the left hand if this is  somewhat of a  blues style ...

Comment: Hehe, it doesn't really provide any more info, except that the chord's E there. But  I uploaded a picture, so you can see for yourself.

Comment: And the bass cleff is not provided separately btw. This is literally _it_

Comment: sorry, I hope I haven't spoiled your question ;) I can delete my comment and my answer if you like.

Comment: I would call this a courtesy accidental.  The difference between "redundant" and "courtesy"  is nil IMHO.   Not really worth worrying about.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - courtesy accidentals really ought to have parentheses, thus showing them to be accidentally on purpose. Any other accidentals which are absolutely necessary and correct don't need them. To be really courteous, the writer and printer should be doing that. Although here, that natural is totally unnecessary!

Comment: @Tim I see your point, but as a (sigh, so old!) very experienced orchestral player, I can say it's a lot easier to read music without extra parentheses crowding the page.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft - with you all the way. Basically can't see the point in that natural  (or other superfluous accidentals) anyway. There's always enough stuff to read without overcrowding, I'm sure you'll agree!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The harmony of the given chord in the 1st 2 bars is in E (major chord), the accidental in front of g you consider (minor third!) is referring to this Chord of E.

Comment: Ah, ok I think I get it! Since the harmony's E and in the E chord there's no G but a G#, they want to alert you on that deviation, right?

Comment: I would say "chord" rather than "key," but this is obviously the correct answer.

Comment: @Creynders that's a possible reason.  It's also possible they didn't want you to think that they'd forgotten to put a sharp sign.  I would have put the natural sign in parentheses.

Comment: @phoog - Yep.  The natural in front of the G is to ban the memory of the G# that went before in the accompaniment.  And yeah, it should have been in parentheses.

Comment: @ScottWallace but it didn't go before; it's simultaneous.

Comment: I have just found a youtube link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HWYpaZTFedE
this isn't a blues, rather something heavy metal or even punk. But the  guitar fillin' contains some blue notes after 0'35"
That's quite the style like I wrote "I'm a pilgrim and a stranger" in 1967 :)

Comment: Hehe, yes I wouldn’t classify the Pixies as ”blues”

Comment: The song references the French engineer Alexandre Gustave Eiffel, who designed the Eiffel Tower and the Statue of Liberty;  "Because of Alexandre Gustave Eiffel, but also because it's funny: in Australia, you often say 'It's a smart Alec'  Australians generally use the word to describe someone who is speaking out of turn; often in a way that makes them appear more intelligent than the person or group they are addressing. In Britain and the United States - a "smart Alec" is the exact opposite of Francis' description—someone who is intelligent, but mean or sarcastic.

Comment: @ScottWallace The problem with parentheses is that they serve a double meaning here, as in some music, the accidental is _optional_, i.e., it's up to the interpreter how he likes it. I personally stopped putting the helper accidentals in parentheses for this reason. I'm still looking for a good notation though as I don't like it now either :-/

Comment: @yo: Do you mean the accidentals in late renaissance and early baroque music for recorder, lute and clavichord or harpsichord and songs. b rotundum or quadratum. look up in these style.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli No, I mean for example option D/D# accidental when a hymn in E minor ends in `D D/D# D`. Or certain modern folk songs where the author himself alternates B or Bb in a C major song when either C or C7 is played, and he simply plays the 7 and sings Bb or does not play the 7 and sings B. The first example is the "romantic 7th" popular at some times by some people (I hate it and remove it whenever I can), the second one is probably a bluetone-inspired innovation.

Comment: @AlbrechtHügli - it should perhaps be pointed out that the accidentals in early music you speak of are modern editor's additions- they don't appear in the original notation, with or without parentheses.

Comment: you're right, Scott,  I really forgot it.

Answer (score 6):

This is where the blues notes blur the key. The 'key' is more likely E, but in Eminor blues the E blues scale uses the same notes as the G major blues. The writer has decided that that G major/E minor key sig, is clearer/ more accurate, but when there is  G note, since it's over an E major chord, it needs to be G natural, and thus it's a courtesy accidental.

It's impossible to write a key sig. for blues, thus the dilemma and the potential need for these courtesies.

Answer (score -1):

the previous chord is an E Major chord, which has a G#, the natural sign is probably to remind you that you that the next bar does not have that, for some reason.

Comment: duplicate answer, therefore dv.

Comment: Also, not really correct. In this type of notation, it is understood that there is E major chord in both first and the second measure, so the G note in the melody is played against G# note in the harmony.